# msmtp cannot send mail via OVH SMTP to root address

Tags: linux, email, ovh, msmtp

I'm trying to get daemons to send email from a Debian 10 Server.

I'm using msmtp-mta with an OVH SMTP server. It's properly configured.

Everything works fine when sending email directly via the mail command, like so :

`echo "test" | mail -s "test" email@domain.com`

However, some daemons like smartd try to send email to root@localhost, but with a malformed recipient address `root`, which the OVH SMTP doesn't like at all :

```
send-mail: recipient address root not accepted by the server
send-mail: server message: 501 5.1.3 Invalid address
send-mail: could not send mail (account default from /etc/msmtprc)
Can't send mail: sendmail process failed with error code 65
```

and in the msmtp log :

```
Apr 25 00:39:49 host=ssl0.ovh.net tls=on auth=on user=***REDACTED*** from=***REDACTED*** recipients=root smtpstatus=501 smtpmsg='501 5.1.3 Invalid address' errormsg='recipient address root not accepted by the server' exitcode=EX_DATAERR
```

I tried adding `root: email@domain.com` to /etc/aliases adn relaoding with `newaliases`, and even put a `.forward` in root's homedir.

Has anyone experienced this before ?  Shouldn't msmtp honor /etc/aliases and/or .forward and replace root's email address ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check with `msmtp -v` if you have another alias that might override the one you're settings. You'll be able to check if it correctly register your aliases using that command.

You may also want to add `aliases /etc/aliases` to your `/etc/msmtprc` file.

You may also add a default alias in `/etc/aliases` if you would like all the mails to be send with a from corresponding: `default: awesome.mail@example.tld`

Comment: It seems that adding aliases /etc/aliases to the config file did the trick, it did not read aliases without it !  Thanks !